# jQuery Validator, make either field required

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am trying to make sure the user enters 1 of 2 fields, either "ExactOrderSize" or "approxOrderSize".

```
<p>Exact size of your order (# of items)</p>
<input id="ExactOrderSize" type="text" name="ExactOrderSize">

<p>Approximate size of your order</p>
<select id="approxOrderSize"  name="approxOrderSize" >
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="0">0-35</option>
    <option value="35">35-50</option>
    <option value="50">50-100</option>
</select>
```

To do this, I am using help from jQuery Validator. Everything works well with it, except for this custom validation rule, which seems to do nothing.

```
$('#quoteform').validate({
  rules: {
    FirstName: {
      required: true
    },
    LastName: {
      required: true
    },
    approxOrderSize: {
      required: function() {
        if($('#ExactOrderSize').val()=="")
          return true;
        else
          return false;
      }
    },
    DateNeededBy: {
      required: true
    }
  }
});
```

My idea was to basically run a function that, if the `#ExactOrderSize` field wasn't filled out, made the `#approxOrderSize` field required. A.K.A. set `required = true`

What we have discovered from StackOverflow answers so far is that the problems lies in the two fields being potentially hidden. When the page first loads neither #ExactOrderSize or #approxOrderSize are initially shown.

They must click one of these two buttons to show that field:
[image]

Depending on which button they select, a slide animation shows the appropriate field.

"Yes" --> Shows the #ExactOrderSize field

[image: Select Yes, they do know the exact order size]

"No" --> Shows the #approxOrderSize field

[image: Select No, so they can enter in an approximate size]

I though this would be a nice user interface, but apparently it is causing problems with the validation messages being able to show, which  makes jQuery Validation not work.

As a solution I tried:

```
$('#quoteform').submit(function() {
    $('#not-exact').show();
    $('#yes-exact').show();
 });
```

That way all fields would be showing after the form submits.. but it still doesn't work.

P.S. Actual page is [HERE](http://texasca.com/quote.php) if you would like to look at it.

Comment: @Michael Hamilton thank you for your contribution, I have edited the question to reflect further understanding of the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am trying to make sure the user enters 1 of 2 fields

**There is already a rule built into this plugin called `require_from_group` that does exactly this.**

1. Include [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.1/additional-methods.js) to get this rule.
2. Add a `class` to both of these fields, `ExactOrderSize` and `approxOrderSize`.  Something like `ordersize`.
3. Declare the rule within the `.validate()` method like this...

   ```
   rules: {
       ExactOrderSize: {
           require_from_group: [1, '.ordersize']
       },
       approxOrderSize: {
           require_from_group: [1, '.ordersize']
       },
       // your other fields/rules
   },
   ```
4. Use [the `groups` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#groups) to ensure there's only one error message for both of these fields.

   ```
   groups: {
       ordersize: "ExactOrderSize approxOrderSize"
   },
   ```
5. Use [the `errorPlacement` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#errorplacement) to place the error message in a position that makes more sense for these two fields.

   ```
   errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
       if ($(element).hasClass("ordersize")) {
           error.insertBefore(element.prev('p')); // custom error placement
       } else {
           error.insertAfter(element);  // default error placement
       }
   }
   ```
6. **NOTE**: The plugin will ignore all hidden fields by default.  To disable this feature, simply set [the `ignore` option](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#ignore) to `[]` and nothing will be ignored.  Then you can simply show/hide the input fields based on some custom event handlers.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/b0qe6Ljg/**

Comment: Ouch, still have an issue somehow. I followed everything you recommended, the problem is that it now throws a validation error now even if you do fill out one of the fields.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery Validator rules are applied to elements with a matching `name` attribute, not a matching `id` attribute. Try this:

```
OrderRange: {
  required: function() {
    if($('#exactOrderSize').val()=="")
      return true;
    else
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I reworked the code slightly to fix that error. Still does not work :(

Comment: Now the id of the input is `ExactOrderSize` but your jQuery selector is `exactOrderSize`.

Comment: I actually fixed that in the code already, just forgot to update that on the StackOverflow question. Change is reflected now.

Comment: Your rules look good then. Are you actually calling `$('#quoteform').valid()` anywhere (e.g. when the form is submitted)?

Comment: No I don't, I think jQuery Validator does that for me. They would have to, because the other required rules all work.

Comment: I believe in order to validate a `<select>` element, the first `<option>` must have a `value` attribute. Have you tried adding `value=''` to it?

Comment: Ok, tried that. I added `value=""` to the `approxOrderSize`. Did not make it work :(

Answer (score 1):

Playing around with this in firebug a bit I think I have a solution.
When the user submits the form and you do validation, before you return `true` or `false` in the validation for `approxOrderSize`, we should show the right field and hide the other one.  Example, if the user did not enter anything into the `ExactOrderSize` field, when they submit the form the validator for `approxOrderSize` checks if `ExactOrderSize` has a value.  If it doesn't have a value, hide that field and show `approxOrderSize`, *then* return `true`.

```
approxOrderSize: {
  required: function() {
    if($('#ExactOrderSize').val()=="")
      $("#NoExact").trigger("click");
      return true;
    else
      $("#YesExact").trigger("click");
      return false;
  }
}
```

At least in my experimenting, this seems to work because it shows the field that is now to be required and shows validation message for that field.

Comment: You are right about 1 thing! If those fields are completely showing, ex. I take the functions hiding them completely off, the validation works! However, your solution did not work for me.  The next thing I tried was to show the fields on form submission: ` $('#quoteform').submit(function() {
  $('#not-exact').show();
  $('#yes-exact').show();
 });
 ` that did not work either... :/

Comment: When you say it didn't work, are you saying that the validation didn't work or that the fields didn't not hide/unhide?

Comment: The fields unhide, then it doesn't throw the appropriate error, and lets the form submit anyway.

Comment: As a control test, I made the fields never hidden in the first place, and my validation rules work as expected.

Comment: *I'm saying the fields unhide the way I wrote it, slightly different then how you wanted to unhide the fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work for you. Here i made function call on submit of form, which checks either among two elements must be filled.

```js
function validateMyForm() {
  var a = document.getElementById('exsize').value.length;
  var b = document.getElementById('opt').value.length;
  if (a == 0 && b == 0) {
    alert("Please fill either of the Fields");
  } else {
    //success
  }
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit='return validateMyForm()'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Exact size of order" id="exsize" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select id="opt">
          <option value="" disabled selected>Select Size</option>
          <option value="A">A</option>
          <option value="B">B</option>
          <option value="C">C</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="submit" value="submit" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: I would prefer to still use the jQuery Validator tools I already have setup, this would require me to do something completely else. It has to be possible to do with the jQuery Validator library...